UK Roommate dies, has suitcase full of money, other roommate goes crazy, moves to attic
In the early to mid 1990's we rented a movie that took place in the UK, I think.  I believe it was three roommates sharing a flat.  The newest roommate dies (I think he OD's on drugs in his room) and they find a suitcase full of money.  They get paranoid about the situation.  One roommate totally loses it and goes up into the attic with the money and starts drilling holes so he can spy on everyone else below.  Bad guys show up looking for the money and hit one guy in the shins with a crowbar and toss a guy in a large freezer and generally torture folks looking for the cash.  Name that movie?

Shallow Grave (1994), the first Danny Boyle movie, starring Ewan McGregor. Three roommates (a journalist, a doctor, and an accountant) search for a new flatmate. They find the mysterious poet Hugo who passes away shortly after, leaving a suitcase full of money. They dispose the body but can't really cope with the money and the situation which leads to e.g. David, the account, to move to the attic.

Great frickin' movie! Not my usual choice, but boy it was good.
